# Use input text box value as string variable for JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to use a variable as a key for JSON. In the below example, I know the interpreter is looking for 'word' on my object. I would like to make it understand that 'word' is a variable.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" />
<button id="submit">Go</button>

// JavaScript
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"dog":"A dog is a mammal.", "eagle":"An eagle is a bird."}');
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var word = $('input[id=text]').val();
    alert(obj[word]);
                          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `'input[id=text]'` selector you are trying to select input with id=text, but you don't have it in markup. Maybe you meant

`$('input[type=text]').val();`

or

```
<input id="text" type="text" />
```

Look at your fixed example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UcAEY/)